# Selenium Webdriver in VS with C# - Using promises

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, asynchronous, automated-tests

I actually haven't found a definitive yes or no answer for this question. Can Selenium WebDriver use promises or callbacks rather than having to use Thread.Sleep or some other polling method?

Currently working with an automation solution using C# with WebDriver added via NuGet to test React based Javascript web pages.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: `WebDriverWait` and `ExpectedConditions` will probably accomplish what you're trying to do, although polling is involved.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are testing JavaScript based UI pages. To test API(services) we cannot use WebDriver. Using Selenium WebDriver you can test only web pages.

As per my understanding if we use programming languages like C#/ Java we can use only [3 type of waits](http://www.guru99.com/implicit-explicit-waits-selenium.html) (implicit, Explicit, Fluent) in selenium.

In my current project we are testing web pages which was developed using JavaScript. To test these we are using [Protractor](http://www.protractortest.org)(based on WebDriverJS) with cucumberJS. As we write our test automation in JavaScript we have callback methods. I guess if we use C# for test automation callback method is not possible

Comment: Yeah sorry you're right, testing JavaScript based web pages. I was looking at Protractor before but rather than AngularJS my company opted towards React. They've always primarily used C# to develop their test Framework/Solution but I'm starting to think a JS approach would have been better

Answer (score 0):

Yes, WebDriver C# allow you to wait based on some conditions to avoid using `Sleep`s. A typical example would be to wait for some DOM element(s) to show up after an async operation is performed:

```
var node = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 3, 0)).Until(
                ExpectedConditions.PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(
                    By.XPath(".//*[contains(@ng-bind,'item.Value')]"))).First();
node.Click();
```

This waits a maximum of three seconds for at least one element matching provided XPath to show up.

`ExpectedConditions` class has various static methods to test for existence, visibility, clickability and so on.

**Side note:** Related to the comment - which WebDriver flavor is used may a matter of taste, but a very short analysis has been performed in [this article](http://www.nechai.net/2016/06/16/c-vs-javascript-for-selenium-tests/).